# Landau Functional - Phase Transitions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, statistical-mechanics, phase-transition

The Landau functional of a second order phase transition can be written as follows:

$$F_{0}[\eta] = \frac{1}{2}t \eta^{2} + u \eta^{4} \, ,$$ with $u>0$. Considering the existence of deformity, through the implementation of a new order parameter $\epsilon$ we have the following Landau expansion:

$$F_{0}[\eta] = \frac{1}{2}t \eta^{2} + u \eta^{4} + \lambda \epsilon \eta^{2} + \frac{1}{2}k \epsilon^{2} \, (\star) \,,$$ where $\lambda$ is the coupling constant with the deformation and $k$ is the elastic constant.

After reading @mikestone comment and re-reading Ginzburg-Landau theory, in fact, there is a need for a cubic term on $\eta$ to transform a Landau functional, which describes a 2nd order phase transition into one that describes a 1st order phase transition. This term, usually, vanishes from symmetry arguments.

This is a phenomenological justification, but how can I justify it by manipulating the Landau functional? Is it enough to show that $\frac{dF}{d\eta} = 0$ is discontinuous when we do not consider cubic term and continuous when we consider it?